# Performance of string-backed enums in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, time-complexity

I have quite a few enums in Swift that are backed by `Strings`. This makes sense given what the enums are representing, and is practical given that the following code block never has to be written:

```
public enum MyEnum : String {
    ...
    func stringValue() -> String {
        switch self {
            ...
        }
    }
    // I can just use .rawValue() instead.
}
```

Something I haven't been able to find is much information on the internal workings and performance of Enums that are backed by non-Integral types. Specifically I am looking for answers to the following questions:

1. Is Enum comparison still guaranteed to be O(1), and if so is this via `String` hashing or do Enums get their own `==` operator that works across its possible values regardless of the underlying type ("true O(1)")?
2. What is the complexity of the `Enum(rawValue:)` constructor for both integral and non-integral types?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at this code:

```
enum A {
    case A1, A2
}

enum B : Int {
    case B1 = 1
    case B2
}

enum C : String {
    case C1
    case C2
}

A.A1.hashValue    // 0
A.A2.hashValue    // 1

B.B1.hashValue    // 0
B.B2.hashValue    // 1

C.C1.hashValue    // 0
C.C2.hashValue    // 1
```

As you can see the `hashValue` of any enum is equal to the number of the case, regardless of the `rawValue` and if there even is one. This is most certainly because underneath, every enum is just a number and the `rawValue` is just an array that maps those numbers (indices) to the corresponding value. Therefore

1. Enum comparison is always just a comparison between two numbers, you can just compare the `hashValue`s -> O(1) complexity (untested, but I'm pretty sure)
2. I don't know how initializing with a raw value works, most likely it's O(1) though (wrong, it's O(n)!, see edit below), because all the possible `RawValue` types are `Hashable` and therefore it's possible to store them in a Hashmap which would mean O(1) indexing.

That said, an enum may be implemented like this:

```
enum M : RawRepresentable {
    case M1    // rawValue = 4, hashValue = 0
    case M2    // rawValue = 7, hashValue = 1

    typealias RawValue = Int

    // Int is Hashable -> Store in Dictionary -> O(1)
    static let rawToEnum : [RawValue : M] = [
        4 : .M1,
        7 : .M2
    ]

    // hashValue is index of this array
    static let hashToRaw : [RawValue] = [
        4,
        7
    ]

    var rawValue : RawValue {
        return M.hashToRaw[hashValue]
    }

    init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        if let m = M.rawToEnum[rawValue] {
            self = m
        } else {
            self = .M1    // Failed, assign a value to let it compile
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It seems like initializing an enum is O(n) (where n is the number of cases) complexity!

I made some performance tests, where I created 4 different enums with 128, 256, 512, 1024 cases each. I then made the program choose 128 random rawValues of each of those enums, make an array of them and repeat that array 20 times (to get more accurate times). Then the enum is getting initialized with each of these rawValues. Here are the results (release build):

```
Default rawValue: 20 repetitions
 128 cases -> 0.003 sec (33% StDev)
 256 cases -> 0.006 sec (14% StDev)
 512 cases -> 0.014 sec (15% StDev)
1024 cases -> 0.025 sec (10% StDev)
```

You can check out the test project I created [here](https://github.com/Kametrixom/EnumTestsPerformance/tree/master) (XCode 7 beta 6)

Another EDIT: I added enums to the test project, which conform to `RawRepresentable` the way I showed above, again using exactly the same setup with 128, 256, 512 and 1024 cases. Turns out (as expected) it's O(1)! So apparently creating your own enum is faster! I just don't understand why the Swift devs didn't do it like this... Performance btw is this for the custom implementation of RawRepresentable for 200 more repetitions (10 times the amount of enum initilizations than with default rawValues):

```
Custom rawValue: 200 repetitions
 128 cases -> 0.008 sec ( 7% StDev)
 256 cases -> 0.008 sec (15% StDev)
 512 cases -> 0.010 sec (19% StDev)
1024 cases -> 0.008 sec (26% StDev)
```

Comment: I did some further testing and can confirm that enum creation from a raw value is indeed `O(n)`. There is a noticeable speed jump for creating an enum value from the raw value of the first case in the definition vs. the last case (or a non-existent case). Unfortunately, for object-backed enums (even Int), it appears that the `==` operator is carried out on all raw values to determine equality. For a string-backed enum, `==` is therefore `O(nm)` where `n` is the number of cases and `m` is the avg. backing string length. Explicitly comparing `.hashValues` appears to take it back to O(1) though.

Comment: @Ephemera I cannot confirm this, I added some tests for enum comparison to [my project](https://github.com/Kametrixom/EnumTestsPerformance/tree/master). How did *you* do the tests?

Comment: Ah ignore me, sorry. As I was describing how I tested I realised the construction was time-determining, not the comparison.

Comment: when i put in your first example into playgrounds, i don't get hash values equivalent to number of case. i get the same length hash value for any enum. example - A.A1.hashValue    // -614164750330540591
A.A2.hashValue    // 6400483729318727726